# codeigniter $this->db->like is case sensitive

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Here is the code.

```
function get_autoComplete($tbl, $data, $field, $value, $where='',$group_by=false,$limit=''){
    $this->db->select($data);
    $this->db->from($tbl);
    if($where!=''){
        $this->db->where($where);
    }
    $this->db->like($field, $value);
    if($group_by == true){
    $this->db->group_by($field);
    }
    if($limit !='')
    {
        $this->db->limit($limit);
    }
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

In the second select statement, it seems as though `like($field, $value)` is case sensitive.
I want it to be insensitive, so I can search without worrying about upper and lower case.

it has something to do with

```
$this->db->like($field, $value);
```

Comment: What is the collation type of that column in the table?

Comment: @anonymous
im not sure but i guess its utf8-bin

Comment: Normally mysql do case insensitive search. only some collations have case sensitive search. You can use following query to find the collation. Select the table and run `SHOW TABLE STATUS`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no case insensitive version of the like function. What you can do is transform both sides of the comparison to lower case, so that you take that out of the equation.

`like('LOWER(' .$field. ')', strtolower($value))`

Comment: Brilliant, sorted out my problem

Comment: You're a life saver (y)

Comment: Nice and simple solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the party!

CodeIgniter 3 has the feature in `like()`.
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-similar-data

Haven't used CI4 yet, so can't be sure there.